# Cant make container overflow-x scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table container that I want it to be scrollable on a smaller resolution, but I am missing something that won't let me do it. I'll provide CodePen code below. .overflow-scroll__mobile
this class to be scrollable overflow-x.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .overflow-scroll__mobile {
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-scroll__mobile">
    <table class="table transactions-history-table">
    </table>
</div>
```

CODE:
https://codepen.io/gkrialashvili/pen/eYWKwRQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table always adjusts to the width of the page unless you specify a width.

The overflow-x will only force show the scrollbar when there is nothing overflowing the within the parent div.

Set a min-width to the table to an appropriate value (say 640px) and max-width of the container div to equal or less than page width(<=100vw) then your container will automatically have the horizontal scroll without needing to force overflow-x. You can't use percentage(say 100%) as it would set the div to its contents min width.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that let me change it and Ill update the codepen in a secon

Comment: So Ive tried to add min-width to overflow-scroll__mobile and to the table to but it just overflows out of the main container and doesnt give scroll

Comment: You need to add min-width to the table and max-width to "overflow-scroll__mobile" less than page width (say 90vw ) only when page width is less than the table width. Since you are using bootstrap, setting max-width as vw unit will set it off.

Comment: I was wrong about overflow being automattic. You will still need to set "overflow-x: auto;"

Comment: .overflow-scroll__mobile {
    max-width: 90vw;
    
  }
  .transactions-history-table{
    min-width: 750px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }  something like this?

Comment: .overflow-scroll__mobile { max-width: 90vw;overflow-x: auto; } .transactions-history-table{ min-width: 750px; } this